# Enviar contenido de dos formularios con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Tengo un archivo en PHP en dónde se reciben datos de tipo POST para mostrarlos en consola, estos son NIT y método de pago.

PHP:

```
<?php
$sNit = $_POST["ingresoNIT"];
$sMetodoPago = $_POST["metodoPago"];


echo json_encode('Correcto: <br>NIT:'.$sNit);
echo json_encode('Correcto: <br>METODOPAGO:'.$sMetodoPago);
?>
```

El NIT y el método de pago están en dos formularios distintos, y necesito enviar ese contenido de los dos formularios al archivo PHP para hacer las validaciones, mi código es el siguiente:

```
                var nitFinal = document.getElementById('nit');
                var metodoPagoFact = document.getElementById('metodoPagoFactura');

                var datos = new FormData(nitFinal);
                var datos2 = new FormData(metodoPagoFact);

                fetch('../controlador/nuevaFactura/facturaFinal/csInsertarFacturaFinal.php',{
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: datos
                })
                    .then( res => res.json())
                    .then( data => {
                        console.log(data)
                })

                fetch('../controlador/nuevaFactura/facturaFinal/csInsertarFacturaFinal.php',{
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: datos2
                })
                    .then( res => res.json())
                    .then( data => {
                        console.log(data2)
                })
```

Necesito enviar ambos form data al mismo PHP, pero solo me está funcionando el último, si quito el primer fetch se guarda el body datos2 que tiene el método de pago, y si quito la segunda, se guarda o envia el NIT, pero necesito que se envien ambos, gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: Porque no lo haces con Ajax de Jquery? es mejor, solo usas **serialize** y concatenas los 2 formularios

Comment: Hola Josué, gracias por comentar, no sé cómo podría hacerlo, quizá me puedes dar algún ejemplo para poder ver, saludos!

Comment: Prueba la respuesta que te dieron a ver si te funciona

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías usar `FormData.append()` y `FormData.entries()` en conjunto para obtener un resultado esperado.

```
var datos = new FormData(nitFinal);
var datos2 = new FormData(metodoPagoFact);

// Obtienes las entradas del formulario X para meterlos al fomulario Y.
for (let [key, value] of datos2.entries()) {
    datos.append(key, value);
}

fetch('../controlador/nuevaFactura/facturaFinal/csInsertarFacturaFinal.php',{
    method: 'POST',
    body: datos
})
    .then( res => res.json())
    .then( data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
```

Dicho de otro modo, estas obteniendo ambos formularios y mezclando los valores en uno solo con el fin de enviar todos los datos juntos como si de un solo formulario se tratase.

**Nota:** solo ten cuidado de no tener campos bajo el mismo nombre en ambos formularios pues podría ocasionarte comportamientos indeseados.

Documentación oficial (MDN):

- FormData.append(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append
- FormData.entries(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries

Comment: Excelente respuesta Chofoteddy, gracias, lo validé y está funcionando bien, gracais por la nota, lo tomaré en cuenta, saludos.